# click listeners for each item in listview

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener

Hi I would like to listen for a clicks on each item in list view I have this code that partially does the job but i.e if I have 5 items and i have a method that deletes one of them it always deletes the last one not the one I clicked on. I've read that I should do interface with *onClick* method that takes *view* and *position* into its constructor but then I'd have a listener for whole item in list and I want to have 4 listeners in this case here is code sample:

```
public class FlashCardsDecksArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FileManager> {
interface Callback {
    void onFileDeleted(String fileName);
}

private final Callback mCallback;

private FileManager manager;

public FlashCardsDecksArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<FileManager> files, final Callback callback) {
    super(context, 0, files);
    mCallback = callback;
}
@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    manager = getItem(position);

    if (convertView == null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_view_item, parent, false);
    }


    TextView deckNameTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.deck_name_id);

    Button addCardButton = convertView.findViewById(R.id.action_add_card);

    Button deleteDeckButton = convertView.findViewById(R.id.action_delete);

    Button settingsButton = convertView.findViewById(R.id.action_deck_settings);

    deckNameTextView.setText(manager.getFileName());

    deckNameTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            if(manager.length() == 0){
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), "deck is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            } else{
                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), FlashCardActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("fileName", manager.getFileName());
                getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });

    addCardButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), AddCardActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("fileName", manager.getFileName());
            getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    deleteDeckButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            buildAlertDialog();
        }
    });

    settingsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            if(manager.length() == 0){
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), "deck is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), FlashCardsDeckSettingsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("fileName", manager.getFileName());
                getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
private AlertDialog buildAlertDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure?").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
            .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();
    return builder.create();
}

DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new 
DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        switch (which){
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                manager.deleteFile();
                mCallback.onFileDeleted(manager.getFileName());
                break;
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                //No button clicked
                break;
        }
    }
};
}
```

Comment: Before return convertView;, add setTag(position) to all the views that assigned with OnClickListener, e.g. deckNameTextView.setTag(position)... Inside OnClickListeners, use int pos = view.getTag() to retrieve the position. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setTag(position) and then int pos view.getTag() solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

Pass the position of the item while deleting the item like this

```
deleteDeckButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        buildAlertDialog(position);
    }
});
```

And on clicking positive button delete the item in that particular position from the manager.

```
DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new 
DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        switch (which){
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                //Delete particular position item from manager
                manager.deleteFile(position);
                mCallback.onFileDeleted(manager.getFileName());
                break;
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                //No button clicked
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I would need another variable to store position as it is not declared final plus FileManager class holds only one file in which flashcards from one deck are being saved this adapter is made to handle an ArrayList<FileManager>, I have whole ArrayList of files which represent decks and I want to delete the one I click on so calling manager.deleteFile(position) won't help here.